# Geting multiple dataframe names as a list

Tags: pandas, global

I have 27 dataframes and I want to achieve their names. I put these dataframes in a list like this:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, ...........df27]

dataframe_names = globals()[df_list]
print(dataframe_names)
```

I want to df's names as a list but I am getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'df_list'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "df's names", do you mean the variable names? (e.g. df1, df2, ...)

Comment: I mean, when I write print(df1), I call df

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you are probably missing `quotes` here - `globals()['df_list']`

Comment: I want to assign these dataframe names to another dataframe as a column so, I need dataframe names as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing quotes here - `globals()['df_list']`